# Repair windows 7 installation in Mac (bootcamp)

Tags: windows-7, linux, mac, boot-camp, ios

Recently I tried to install Linux (Debian distribution) in a Mac device which have windows 7 installed too. I did it worng (now I know it) because I did it through windows 7 so, when I restarted, Linux installed the grub but bootcamp do not recognize it like a operative system.

The point is: I would want to recover windows how can I do it without losing any data?

In addiction? Linux system is well installed but I cannot access neither so, may I use it somehow?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So both windows and Linux can not be accessed now?

Comment: Nop. If I choose windows boot it shows the message: "missing operation system" (I think it because the grub erased the windows boot files and bootcamp doesn't know it, I mean during the system loading bootcamp find grub files instead of windows init files so it crush)